# Extract just one line from a big JSON in Java

Tags: java, json, oop, jackson, deserialization

Since my very first days of **Java** + **JSON** I tried to extract just some certain parts of a **JSON**.

But no matter if which of the libraries I used:

- Gson
- json-simple
- javax.json

it never was possible to make it quick and comfortable. Mostly for easy task or even prototyping. It already cost me many hours of different approaches.

1. Going trough the hierarchy of an **JSON**

   ```
   Object jsonObject = gson.fromJson(output, Object.class);
   JsonElement jsonTree = gson.toJsonTree(jsonObject);
   JsonArray commitList = jsonTree.getAsJsonArray();
   JsonElement firstElement = commitList.get(0);
   JsonObject firstElementObj = firstElement.getAsJsonObject();
   System.out.println(firstElementObj.get("sha"));
   JsonElement fileList = firstElementObj.get("files");
   ```

This is dirty code for a reason. It shows how many early approaches looks like and how many people cannot achieve it to do it better early.

2. Deserializing **JSON** to a **Java** Object
   Your have to analyse the complete **JSON** to create an complete **Java**-Object representation just to get access to some single memebers of it. This is a way I never wanted to do for prototyping

**JSON** is an easy format. But using libraries like that is quite difficult and often an problem for beginner. I've found several different answers via **Google** and even **StackOverflow**. But most were quite big larged which required to create a own specific class for the whole **JSON**-Object.

What is the best approach to make it more beginner-friendly?
or
What is the best beginner-friendly approach?

Answer (score 0):

### Generate Plain Old Java Objects from JSON or JSON-Schema

One little helper I found via my research was an **Online-Tool** like 
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

This is a little help, when you know about that. But the negative side I mentioned at point 2 is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jackson (which you tagged), you can use JsonPointer expressions to navigate through a tree object:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode tree = mapper
            .readTree("[ { \"sha\": \"foo\", \"files\": [ { \"sha\": \"bar\" }, { \"sha\": \"quux\" } ] } ]");
    System.out.println(tree.at("/0/sha").asText());
    for (JsonNode file : tree.at("/0/files")) {
        System.out.println(file.get("sha").asText());
    }
```

You could also use the ObjectMapper to convert just parts of a tree to your model objects, if you want to start using that:

```
    for (JsonNode fileNode : tree.at("/0/files")) {
        FileInfo fileInfo = mapper.convertValue(fileNode, FileInfo.class);
        System.out.println(fileInfo.sha);
    }
```

If your target class (FileInfo) specifies to ignore unknown properties (annotate target class with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` or disable `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` on the mapper), then you can simply declare the properties you are interested in.

"Best" is whatever works to get you going.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JsonSurfer](https://github.com/jsurfer/JsonSurfer) to selectively extract value or object from big json with streaming JsonPath processor.

```
JsonSurfer jsonSurfer = JsonSurfer.gson();
System.out.println(jsonSurfer.collectOne(json, "$[0].sha"));
System.out.println(jsonSurfer.collectOne(json, "$[0].files"));
```